# No route matches {:action=>"up_vote", :controller=>"votes", :post_id=>"1"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I've been receiving the following error in my RSpec when trying to get my upvote method to pass:

```
Failures:
1) VotesController#up_vote adds an up-vote to the post
 Failure/Error: post( :up_vote, post_id: @post.id )
 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"up_vote", :controller=>"votes", :post_id=>"1"}
```

Now I can upvote and downvote when I'm on the server, it's just my test that won't work.

Here's my code:

#### votes_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe VotesController do

  include TestFactories
  include Devise::TestHelpers

  describe '#up_vote' do
    it "adds an up-vote to the post" do
      request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] = '/'
      @user = authenticated_user
      @post = associated_post
      sign_in @user

      expect {
        post(:up_vote, post_id: @post.id)
      }.to change { @post.up_votes }.by 1
    end
  end
end
```

#### votes_controller.rb

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_post_and_vote

  def up_vote
    update_vote!(1)
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def down_vote
    update_vote!(-1)
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def update_vote!(new_value)

    if @vote
      authorize @vote, :update?
      @vote.update_attribute(:value, new_value)
    else
      @vote = current_user.votes.build(value: new_value, post: @post)
      authorize @vote, :create?
      @vote.save
    end
  end

  private

  def load_post_and_vote
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])

    @vote = @post.votes.where(user_id: current_user.id).first
  end
end
```

#### routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
  resources :users, only: [:update]
  resources :questions
  resources :advertisements

  resources :topics do
    resources :posts, except: [:index] do
      resources :summaries, only: [:create, :new, :show]
      resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy]

      post '/up-vote', to: 'votes#up_vote', as: :up_vote
      post '/down-vote', to: 'votes#down_vote', as: :down_vote
    end
  end

  get 'about' => 'welcome#about'
  get 'contact' => 'welcome#contact'

  root to: 'welcome#index'

end
```

#### Module providing methods within specs:

```
module TestFactories
  def associated_post(options={})
    post_options = {
        title: 'Post title',
        body: 'Post bodies must be pretty long.',
        topic: Topic.create(name: 'Topic name'),
        user: authenticated_user
    }.merge(options)

    Post.create(post_options)
  end

  def authenticated_user(options={})
    user_options = {email: "email#{rand}@fake.com", password: 'password'}.merge(options)
    user = User.new(user_options)
    user.skip_confirmation!
    user.save
    user
  end
end
```

#### Relevant Rake Routes

```
topic_post_up_vote POST   /topics/:topic_id/posts/:post_id/up-vote(.:format)       votes#up_vote
topic_post_down_vote POST   /topics/:topic_id/posts/:post_id/down-vote(.:format)     votes#down_vote
```

Any ideas why I'm getting this URL generation error?

Comment: It looks like the path for that should be `/posts/:id/up-vote`.  What does `rake routes` return, and is that the same path that you're passing in to your test?

Comment: I added the relevant rake routes above. I honestly don't know how to pass the nested path concerning those routes though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to pass the `topic_id` to the post method like this: `post( :up_vote, post_id: @post.id, topic_id: @post.topic.id )`

Comment: Hmmm. I tried that and this is what I got:


```

VotesController#up_vote adds an up-vote to the post
     Failure/Error: post( :up_vote, post_id: @post.id, topic_id: @post.topic.id )
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"up_vote", :controller=>"votes", :post_id=>"1", :topic_id=>nil}


```

Comment: Doesn't look like your post has a topic associated. If you fix that, the route should work. :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up switching my routes.rb file to the below and got the above vote_controller_spec.rb working.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do



devise_for :users
resources :users, only: [:update]
resources :questions
resources :advertisements

resources :topics do
resources :posts, except: [:index]
end

resources :posts, only: [] do
  resources :summaries, only: [:create, :new, :show]
  resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy]

  post '/up-vote', to: 'votes#up_vote', as: :up_vote
  post '/down-vote', to: 'votes#down_vote', as: :down_vote

end


get 'about' => 'welcome#about'
get 'contact' => 'welcome#contact'



root to: 'welcome#index'


end
```